# How to use or statement in a if statement in openrefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I need to verify 2 values inside a if condition in Openrefine I already tried:

```
if(value > 5.6 | < -33, "inside", "outside")

if(value > 5.6 || < -33, "inside", "outside")

if(value > 5.6 or < -33, "inside", "outside")
```

Answer (score 4):

This one worked -

```
if(or(value > 5.6, value < -33) , "Inside", "Outside")
```

The think, it was easier than expected, GREL language impresses sometimes.